# Cast a BOOL to id in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is my code:

```
[delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setVariablePremierAffichage:) withObject:TRUE waitUntilDone:NO];
```

The problem is that the argument "withObject" only takes an "id" type, so, how can I cast my value "TRUE" to an id type? I also use ARC memory management in Xcode for iOS 5.

Comment: The answer you have gotten is correct. But, rather than jump through hoops to force something like this to work you should ask yourself why you are using `performoSelectorOnMainThread` in the first place? Why not just use `[delegate setVariablePremierAffichage:YES]` directly?

Comment: @Abizem, you are right depending on the context. The OP may be calling this from another thread. Even in that case, using `dispatch_async` instead of `performSelectorOnMainThread:` would allow the method to be called w/o using NSNumber. However, I wouldn't call this "jumping through hoops". It's a reasonable implementation choice, again, depending on context.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pass an `NSNumber`. Use `boolNumber = [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE]`. Your method should be defined as:

```
-(void)setVariablePremierAffichage:(NSNumber *)boolNumber
{
    BOOL value = [boolNumber boolValue];
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to say `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` as the Objective-C convention for BOOLs is `YES` and `NO` instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE`

Comment: Yes it works, but there are conventions and YES/NO is the one for Objective-C.

Comment: ok, this is one convention not worth arguing about. I use YES/NO in my code. Typed TRUE in the answer as the OP used it. Doesn't particularly matter as the meaning is obvious. The conventions that really matter are ones that affect readability, understanding or have an implied meaning (e.g. a method returning an autoreleased object in pre-ARC days, etc).

Answer (score 5):

Use CFbooleanreference and cast it

```
[delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setVariablePremierAffichage:) withObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to cast a primitive to an id.  If you need to call a method dynamically such as with performSelector you will need to use NSInvocation:

```
NSMethodSignature *sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(setVariablePremierAffichage:)];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
BOOL yes = YES;
[invocation setArgument:&yes atIndex:2];
[invocation setTarget:self];
[invocation setSelector:@selector(setVariablePremierAffichage:)];
[invocation invoke];
```

Cheers!